# map() is returning only part of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
a = '0'
b = '256'
mod_add = ['300', '129', '139']
list(map(lambda a, b, x: (a < x) and (x < b), a, b, mod_add))
```

I'd like to check every element in mod_add, but

```
list(map(lambda a, b, x: (a < x) and (x < b), a, b, mod_add))
```

returns only one `False`.
With some values `(a = '100', b = '200')` it returns `'False', 'False', 'False'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you intending to compare strings or would you like to compare the integer values? E.g., 20 < 100 but '20' > '100'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to use `map`:

```
list(map(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), mod_add))
```

Edit:

In response to the desire to `map` only one element from the list, it really doesn't make such sense to me to do that. But if that's what you wish to do, you can try:

```
list(map(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), [mod_add[0]]))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! I also tried to slightly change it (if I need to check only one element for example, but it returns a error:  `>>> list(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), mod_add[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
`

Comment: It really does not make sense to map a single element of a list. But you can , if you really insist, do: `list(map(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), [mod_add[0]]))`.

Comment: I mean, I don't use map() now - I would like to check single element. I'm using `list(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), mod_add[0])`, still I see error ' list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)'. (I already changed a and b to integers (and mod_add to list of integers too))

Comment: yes, it works fine. but it still returns error when i try to get rid of map() - can you please explain why it happens?

Comment: If you want compare `mod_add[0]` with `a` and `b` then just do `(a < mod_add[0]) and (mod_add[0] < b)`. You really don't need `map()` for that.

Comment: Right. (I'm just practicing with functions so right now i'm using them wherever i can :)). Now my last question is why `list(lambda x: (a < x) and (x < b), mod_add[0])` returns error (without map())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123358/discussion-between-abdou-and-grindelwaldus).

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are strings, they will be rightly treated as *iterables* by `map`, not constants as you intend. You should either use a list comprehension or not pass `a` and `b` as parameters to `map`:

```
>>> [a < x < b for x in mod_add]
[False, True, True]
```

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, so `(a < x) and (x < b)` can be replaced with `a < x < b`

---

Comparing integers instead of strings (which is probably what you want) is just another step away:

```
>>> [int(a) < int(i) < int(b) for i in mod_add]
[False, True, True]
```

Comment: Just intersted, is there way to check it with map(), if I change type to int?

Comment: @grindelwaldus Yes, I don't see why not

Answer (score 0):

This is really the kind of thing you should prefer list comprehensions for.

```
min_, max_ = '0', '256'
# do you mean for these to be compared lexicographically?!
# be aware that '0' < '1234567890' < '256' is True

mod_add = ['300', '129', '139']

result = [min_ < mod < max_ for mod in mod_add]
# [False, True, True]
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (now [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)) are mighty tools to be sure, but Python tends to shy away from them in favor of more verbose, easier to read expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '0'
b = '256'
mod_add['300', '129', '139']
map(lambda x: int(a)<int(x)<int(b), mod_add)
```

Output :

```
[False, True, True]
```